# Bot Framework REST API send proactive message to multiple users with one conversation ID

Tags: json, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm wondering if there is a way to send 1:1 message to users using only one conversation id? So instead of looping through each user and generating a conversation id, I'm trying to create a request to generate a conversation ID with multiple members.

See payload below:

POST /v3/conversations

```
{
  "activity": {
    "type": "message",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "text": "Testing"
  },
  "bot": {
    "id": "215000000-00000-0000-00000",
    "name": "Test",
    "aadObjectId": null,
    "role": null
  },
  "isGroup": false,
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "29:asda123123asdad123sdadassaw1233fwmHog5cU9_rRLIauRiA6Mzsdadassaw1233fwm1H",
      "name": null,
      "aadObjectId": null,
      "role": null
    },
    {
      "id": "29:asdadassaw1233fwmHog5cU9_rRLIauRiA6MzE4TJ98ldUVqOm32asd12qCZs5eu_pjL8mUg",
      "name": null,
      "aadObjectId": null,
      "role": null
    }
  ],
  "tenantId": "12312312adasdadtest"
}
```

I'm getting a BadSyntax HTTP 400 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Incorrect conversation creation parameters"
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot Framework API Create Conversation With Multiple Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844489/bot-framework-api-create-conversation-with-multiple-members)

Comment: These two problems are pretty connected, and you should combine them into one, explaining what you're trying and what you ultimately want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message), [creating a conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#create-conversation), and [conversation ID's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide#conversation-id) are all channel-specific so it's important to be explicit about what channel you're using in these situations. From your JSON it looks like you're using Microsoft Teams. Every [conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics) in Microsoft Teams will have a unique conversation ID, and every 1:1 chat between a bot and a user needs to be its own conversation, so there is no way to use only one conversation ID for multiple chats with users.