# Bot Framework API Create Conversation With Multiple Members

Tags: json, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to create a conversation with multiple members and generating a conversation id. My goal is to have the bot message each member listed in the "members" key one-by-one. It works exactly as it should when I only put one item in the "members" key and I am able to generate a conversation id. However, I'm getting an error when I put 2 or more items in the "members" key even though it's supposed to be an array of members.

```
POST /v3/conversations

{
  "activity": {
    "type": "message",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "text": "Testing"
  },
  "bot": {
    "id": "215000000-00000-0000-00000",
    "name": "Test",
    "aadObjectId": null,
    "role": null
  },
  "isGroup": false,
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "29:asda123123asdad123sdadassaw1233fwmHog5cU9_rRLIauRiA6Mzsdadassaw1233fwm1H",
      "name": null,
      "aadObjectId": null,
      "role": null
    },
    {
      "id": "29:asdadassaw1233fwmHog5cU9_rRLIauRiA6MzE4TJ98ldUVqOm32asd12qCZs5eu_pjL8mUg",
      "name": null,
      "aadObjectId": null,
      "role": null
    }
  ],
  "tenantId": "12312312adasdadtest"
}
```

This yields a HTTP 400 Bad Request Error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Incorrect conversation creation parameters"
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot Framework REST API send proactive message to multiple users with one conversation ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842516/bot-framework-rest-api-send-proactive-message-to-multiple-users-with-one-convers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `members` is an array is because it can be used for group conversations. You have set `isGroup` to `false` so you are not creating a group conversation. If you want to create multiple conversations then you will need to send multiple requests, which you've said is working.

Comment: Hello @kyle-delaney, Even when I pass the `isGroup` option as true I still get the same error as the OP posted. I want to create a group conversation with multiple members. Is `POST /v3/conversations` the right API to do so?

Comment: @Guatam - I don't think bots can create group chats, but they can create threads in team channels. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations

Comment: Thank you, quite unfortunate. Is this something planned for the near future?

Comment: Unlikely, but you can provide feedback through the Teams app