# Microsoft Bot Framework API Create Conversation With Multiple Members

Tags: json, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I want to create a conversation with multiple members using Bot Framework API for Microsoft teams bot, but I get the error

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadSyntax",
    "message": "Incorrect conversation creation parameters"
}
```

}

The API I am hitting is - `POST` `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/conversations`

The body -

```
{
"bot": {
  "id": "215000000-00000-0000-00000"
},
"isGroup": true,
"members": [
    {
        "id": "29:1yO0InhR9X61FqwsPnyO0ROgGX_6rBQjIB2UO_ggxdW308dCP8ceY44CIj_h_fDV0v1mQJzm5Q"
    },
    {
        "id": "29:1yO0InhR9X61FqwsPnyO0ROgGX_ggxdW308dCP8ceY44CIj_h_fDV0v1mQJzm5Q"
    }
],
"channelData": {
    "tenant": {
    "id": "812a-4593-95fd-12d43d397474"
    }
}
```

}

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844489/bot-framework-api-create-conversation-with-multiple-members) posted but I tried what is mentioned in it but it didn't work.

Can someone guide me on how can I create a conversation with multiple members using botframework rest API?

Comment: Are you provided the bot details to request body? Could you please share complete request body?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Hey, I have updated the body with the bot details. I tried the request with and without the bot details and it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create group chats with this API, only one-to-one chats or new threads in an existing channel. To interact in a group chat your bot has to be installed in that context by a user, unfortunately.

Comment: So, currently there is no API to create a group chat?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thank you, It's quite unfortunate.